# Unable to handle CORS requests in apache tomcat

Tags: ajax, tomcat7, jax-rs, cors

I am using apache tomcat V7.0. From client side I am making an ajax call to access a REST service hosted in apache tomcat server and built using JAX-RS. I am having only one rest GET method. Client is not on the same domain as of server. Let's say I had saved the html on my desktop and than I am running the html file. This means I am having this html file in no domain. The response I am getting is from server is: [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 16ms]. This is a CORS error. To get rid of this error I had done following things:
Client side code:

```
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST");
   //Normal ajax calls of setting url and opening requests follows
```

Server side web.xml configuration:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
  <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
  <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
  <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
  <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
  <param-value>10</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Even after adding all the cors handling, both at server and client side I am getting cors error.
I guess the request is not even reaching the filters and is getting rejected. Is there some configuration that is required in server to allow the request to pass by. In apache I searched on web and found that we can do so in .htaccess file but what should be done in case of apache tomcat?

Comment: 403 is not specifically a cors error.  Please add the stack trace to your questionfor a better answer.

Comment: The exact error that I got in mozilla is:                                                                     Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/restMailer/rest/mailService?query={%22subject%22:%22Test%201%22,%22vendorCode%22:%22V00002%22,%22name%22:%22Test%202%22,%22enquiry%22:%22Test%203%22,%22contactNumber%22:%22Test%204%22,%22email%22:%22Test%205%22,%22icode%22:%22as723asd343ascfgru323sA!%22}. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: Looks like there is not solution to this problem. I just wanted to changes the header properties whenever a request comes to port 8080 of tomcat.

Comment: If someone is caught in this kind of problem and find any solution please do post on this thread. For the workaround I used JSONP instead and in someway browser allowed CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to setting the **cors.allowed.origins** with your client info? like this:

```
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>http://10.3.50.139:8481</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

Comment: No I didn't tried it out. For which servlet these init params should be specified?